# C Man or manual in text or other format to use in command line shell in linux

Tags: linux, shell, manual, manpage

Im looking for some kind of C text manual or man pages for C syntax or cockbook 
which i can check in command line shell mode .
Thanks

Comment: From the shell prompt, type: `man man`

Comment: not realy system calls and such but real cookbook for C 
some kind of book

Comment: You've been here long enough to know you can't ask for library and such  recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

You could use **pandoc** (available [here](http://pandoc.org/index.html)) to convert pretty much anything that you like the style of into manpages - whether that is HTML, MS-Word documents or ePUB books.

So, take the *"GNU C Reference Manual"* [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html), and convert that into manpages with **pandoc** as follows:

```
pandoc -V title="C Programming" -V section=1 -s -t man https://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html -o C.1
```

Then you could copy that to `usr/local/share/man/man1` and access it with:

```
man C
```

Or, don't mix it in with your system manpages, and instead change your MANPATH environment variable.

Or you could use the *"GNU C Library"* as your starting point ([here](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html)), or heck, have them both!

Answer (score 0):

The man page for "C" syntax alone would be huge :-) "The C Programming Language" by Kernighan & Ritchie is still a thorough and readable way to learn C.

Comment: does it have text file version ?

Comment: There are ebook versions. Lmgtfy...
If you want something free, qv http://www.onlineprogrammingbooks.com/c/